# Django i18n not working

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I cannot get translations to show up for my templates.  Here is what I have done:

1. In my template file (index.html), I have loaded i18n and used the `trans` tag where I want translations.
2. In my project directory, I rand `./manage.py makemessages -l es`
3. My django.po file is in `./conf/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`
4. I edited this file with the translations.
5. I then ran `./manage.py compilemessages`
6. I set my `LANGUAGE_CODE` to 'es' in settings.py
7. Added `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in between SessionMiddleware and CommonMiddleware.
8. Restarted Django, refreshed my page.

Only the english representations are still showing.  What am I doing wrong here?  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem... My po files were in `./conf/locale` instead of just `./locale`.

The reason I created `./conf/locale` was because when I rand `django-admin.py makemessages`, it instructed me to do so.  However, if it's in your local project directory, then it is just simply `./locale`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting `LOCALE_PATHS` in your settings file? That fixed it for me...for more info check out [an answer I wrote for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947426/1149774) or django's [official documentation for the `LOCALE_PATHS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths).

Answer (score 2):

Django's `LocaleMiddleware` tries to determine the locale from the given request and replaces the `LANGUAGE_CODE` accordingly. It goes through the following steps:

1. Checks the session for a session variable called `django_language`. Set the language to the given locale in this session. If not existing it goes to 2.
2. Checks the cookies for a similar variable set (you can define the name yourself). It not existing it goes to 3.
3. Tries to determine the language from the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header. If not possible it will go to 4.
4. At last it will use the `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting as given locale.

In all steps except 4 it will check if the language is given in your `LANGUAGES` setting, which is a tuple of 2-tuples representing language code and language title. Make sure you set/overwrite the default, since the default would be a tuple of all available Django languages.

**If you have multiple languages in your Django site:**

Make sure your session or cookies are set correctly. You could use Django's internal view for setting the language (`django.views.i18n.set_language`).

**If you got only one language:**

If you only have Spanish you usually don't need to bother with this. Just make sure `LANGUAGES` and `LANGUAGE_CODE` is set. It will not attempt to set the pages language to your browsers language if it is not provided in `LANGUAGES`. Additionally you should make sure that `USE_I18N = True`. That should be the default though, so make at least sure you didn't set it to `False` somewhere.

Comment: Yep. I have followed all of this... I can't seem to get it to translate still.  Its driving me crazy. I'm sure I'm missing something not on that list or something obscure. Maybe after some sleep I'll get it...