# {% trans "string" %} not working on templates but {% trans variable %} does

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates

I'm quite new to Django and I'm working on a project with i18n, the thing is that I have translated some variables using  `.manage.py makemessages / compilemessages`  on my template file, but when I use  `{% trans "my string" %}`  I got the same `"my string"` for all the languages.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code for the *views.py* and the *idioma.html*

---

**views.py:**

*#some code here...*

```
def idioma(request):
    output = _("Mensaje en espanol")
    return render_to_response( 'idioma/idioma.html', { 'idioma' : output }, context_instance = RequestContext(request) )
```

---

**idioma.html**

```
{% load i18n %}

< form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}

        < input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />

        < select name="language" >

        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

        {% for language in languages %}

            < option value="{{ language.code }}">
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            < /option>
        {% endfor %}

        </select>

        < input type="submit" value="Go" />

    < /form>

    La cadena es: {% trans idioma  %}

    {% trans "carro" %}
```

---

The application translates the idioma variable from the .po and .mo files in locale/path/to/language/

But it doesn't translate the {% trans "carro" %} string.

What's going on?

Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you manually translated the string in the .po ?

`makemessages` just adds "carro" to the .po, generating something like this in the .po file

```
#: idioma.html:45
msgid "carro"
msgstr ""
```

and then you have to edit the .po **manually** adding the translation for that string, in this way:

```
#: idioma.html:45
msgid "carro"
msgstr "car"
```

Then, when you are done translating all the .po strings, you can run `compilemessages`: it will compile your translations.

**Note:** always remember to look for `,fuzzy` translations. 
If you have something like this in your .po

```
#: idioma.html:45
#, fuzzy
msgid "carro"
msgstr "car"
```

That means that django, for some reason, tried to translate the string by itself *(it usually happens when you already used that string in a piece of code that you aren't using anymore)*.

You have to review the translation and delete the `#, fuzzy` line: any translation tagged with `#, fuzzy` won't be translated in your pages.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar problem and was able to resolve it by setting `LOCALE_PATHS` in my settings file. `LOCALE_PATHS` is a tuple of directory paths where django looks for .mo and .po files. Here's an example:

```
# settings.py
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/path/to/your/project/locale',
)
```

Read [django's official documentation on `LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I tracked the code whole night and found some clues. Mainly in trans_real.py and gettext.py. You can put a breakpoint in "translation" function.

1. The translation code are executed only once when app starts. So you
   need to reload the uwsgi to load the new version.
2. Po file is never used. gettext.py use "mo" file only.(in my laptop).
   So you have to compile messages after changing.
3. The "-" in the language code will be converted to "_" in locale
   path. For example "zh-CN" will be converted to "zh_CN". That's why
   the translation file cannot be found. I think it will be better if
   just using two characters as the language code. And the case
   sensitive should be considered in Linux system.

Comment: for me it was the en_ca vs en-ca

Comment: This was the case for me too

Answer (score 1):

In some cases `{% trans "your string " %}` doesn't work.

I recommend you to use `blocktrans` instead of trans for strings.

How to use blocktrans:

```
{% blocktrans %} your string {% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: {% blocktrans %}String{% endblocktrans %} and also {% trans "String" %}

Comment: When I change my language, it translates the variable from the .po files generates with ./manage.py  with {% trans myVariable %}, so I think that the language selector is working fine.

Comment: carro is a variable or simple string

Comment: It's a string, I put any string and it just doesn't translate

Comment: i tried in mine system boss and its working fine i don't what you are missing

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same issue. I explained it with details in [this link under another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826101/django-translation-template-trans-something/38546533#38546533#22695869).

Briefly, my problem has been solved by reloading the server with this code:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi reload
```

Now, everytime I change the phrases and after compiling language files, I reload the server too to see the changes.
I hope this solves some one's problem.