# {% trans "something" %} doesn't work even when i filled the .po correctly

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm desperately trying to make it work but I haven't luck. I checked this topic but it seems he didn't fill the msgstr properly, I did!

[{% trans "string" %} not working on templates but {% trans variable %} does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101811/trans-string-not-working-on-templates-but-trans-variable-does)

I'm doing 
- django-admin makemessages -l en-us
- django-admin compilemessages

```
#: templates/dashboard.html:8 templates/dashboard.html.py:10
msgid "test"
msgstr "test test"

#: templates/dashboard.html:11
msgid "customers"
msgstr "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you enabled i18n in your settings

Comment: also change langauge preference to the langauge you want to convert.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yes I have enabled in settings USE_I18N = True and the language code: LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

Comment: Are you doing django compilemessages before writing translation?