# django translation template {% trans "something" %}

Tags: python, django, templates, translation

Ok I have been searching like crazy for this I think simple problem.

I use Django 1.4

The problem is that django won't translate a simple {% trans "work" %} in my template.

This is what I have done:

Settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/m00p/PycharmProjects/astrid/locale'
)
```

this is my map structure:

```
/
myproject/
apps/
locale/
template/
```

So I runned

> django-admin.py makemessages -l nl -i settings.py

and it did succesfully created in the locale folder nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po, I then edit the translation It found in the django.po

```
#: templates/base.html:22
msgid "work"
msgstr "ddddddddddddd"
```

I then run the compile command

> django-admin.py compilemessages

and it also succesfully created a django.mo file in the correct folder

I added this also in the myproject/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'front.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

I added this in the base.html file to be able to change the language

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

So when I go to the website I get 127.0.0.1:8000/en/ in the url, this is correct because englisch is the default language, when I then change it with the form to NL, It redirects to 127.0.0.1:8000/nl/ but the text I translated didn't change. I'm also sure that the language is NL because when I display {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} it says NL.

Anybody know why it doesn't change?

Thanks m00p

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

During the process when I was adding things I forgot for it to work, I restarted my deployment server, but I **didn't cleared the cache of my browser** it was still using the old pages, so when I cleared my browser data in Chrome and revisited the page and changed the language it translated it correctly.  Thanks for the suggestions anyway!

Comment: i am also using this multiple language concept and I did exactly what you have done but in my django.po file it does not contain my templates file lines which i can edit e.g. as your .po file contain `#: templates/base.html:22
msgid "work"`....BUT rather than that it contains all the files **inside site-packages/django** (i.ie, admin part)  I don't want to edit these admin files but I edit to see that weather translation is working or not but it does not working for this admin part too...................so my main problem is how to show my template data which I can edit

Comment: I have already specified `{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Hello" %}`

inside my template so that .po file picks it and I can add translated data in .po file............ but still it does not picks these templates inside .po file..... ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django 1.4 the locale directory at project root is not longer supported. You should add it to `LOCALE_PATHS` setting, which is empty by default. [Django Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths).

However the management commands involved in locale generation, seems to work, so I don't know if you already did it.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 13):

I just spent few hours trying to fix this issue in Django 1.5 while working on my new project [Sportolio](http://www.sportolio.pl) and it turned out I was missing a **comma** at the end of LOCALE_PATH

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/path/to/my/project/locale/',
)
```

This is very crucial, as Django expects LOCALE_PATHS to be a **TUPLE** not a String.

I hope it save someone's life :)

Comment: Definitely just saved mine!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. Part of phrases were translation but most of them just showed the key. We have two main languages en and fa. Both had the same problem.
I reviewed all the same problems and every single document online about the django translations. I can say I tried almost everything. 
The only difference was we were testing on the production server.
And I didn't reload the server! 
So this one-line command took me out of my misery:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi reload
```

what I was doing wrong was I restarted wsgi instead of uwsgi!

If you like to do what I did, here it is:
I do the steps in this order on server:

```
django-admin makemessages -l en
django-admin makemessages -l fa
```

add Persian phrases and some english text to test.

```
django-admin compilemessages
python manage.py clear_cache
python manage.py runserver
```

Server runs with no errors. But non of the changes in en or fa take place. It looks that django is loading from old cache. So, I deleted the whole cache, and even deleted all the files from server and installed the whole project again. Yet the same issue.

I made messages from my django on my laptop and sent it to server.
Also, I tried different text editors and translation tools such as
poedit to generate po and mo files. Yet the problem keeps showing.

I used and replaced trans tags to see if it works in any of them:

```
{% trans ' ' %}
{% trans " " %}
{% blocktrans %} {% endblocktrans %}
{% trans "xyz" az XYZ %} {{ XYZ }}
{{ _() }}
```

none of them worked!

But reloading the server put everything in order.
I hope it might be helpful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

The position you key the command matter.

In my case, this is my project structure:

```
myproject/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    apps/
        migrations/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

If I call `makemessages` at mysite folder, like this:

```
D:\...\myproject\mysite> python ../manage.py makemessages -all
```

it will not get the string in HTML `{% trans "str" %}`.
But if I call makemessages at myproject folder, like this:

```
D:\...\myproject> python manage.py makemessages -all
```

it works! It finds all `{% trans "str" %}` in HTML.
So be careful about the location you are.